# Analytics site list appending index.php to pages

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Under behavior > site content > all pages there are links such as /shop/christmas.html/index.php which don't exist. The correct url is /shop/christmas.html/. I have created a 301 redirect in case anyone is visiting the index.php page.

Why is analytics appending my pages with index.php?

Comment: Probably somebody entered index.php to the default page setting in the view settings. That would add index.php to every url with a trailing slash.

Comment: You're right. I removed this so from now on my pages should show without it?

Comment: Future hits, yes. Data that has been collected before you changed the setting will not change back (alas it is not possible in GA to change data that's already been processed).